# Installing Linux on Acer Laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, system-installation, kali-linux

I have an Acer Laptop Aspire E-5 573G It came with pre-installed Windows 10. I tried installing possibly every Linux OS (Ubuntu, Kali, Parrot Sec, Linux Mint) along side Win10 but didn't work. So I got rid of the Windows 10, cleared my whole hard disk and now when I try to install Linux I'm still stuck at the same point.

When I try to run live/install Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Parrot Sec I'm stuck at a black screen with a blinking underscore (_) I googled and tried with nomodest on and with couple more settings but it doesn't work.

But when I try to install Parrot Sec in fail safe mode I'm stuck on the following screen.

[image: Stuck here in Parrot Sec in Fail Safe mode.]

I don't understand what the problem actually is. I'm currently installing these OS in Legacy mode because when I try to install them in UEFI it doesn't detect any bootable device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a BIOS issue. This solution is from [the Acer forum](https://community.acer.com/t5/E-and-M-Series-Laptops/Acer-Aspire-e5-573g-You-can-not-install-any-one-Linux/td-p/386009).

1. Go to: http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers
2. Search by Product Model:
   Aspire E5-573G
3. Select the right OS and download a bios. In my case I downloaded 1.15.
4. Run the `ZRT_115.exe`. 
   It will fail.
5. But before you close the installer, go to `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\`
6. Search for a folder (random letters).tmp 
   There should be a `H2OFFT-W.exe` and `zrt.rd` file in there. 
   Just copy this folder and close the failing install.
7. In that copied folder, edit the `platform.ini` file.

   Before:

   ```
   [BIOSVersionFormat]
   ;[nb4-version] +
   BIOSVFEnable=1
   VersionFormat=XN.NN
   ```

   After:

   ```
   [BIOSVersionFormat]
   ;[nb4-version] +
   BIOSVFEnable=1
   VersionFormat=XN.DD
   ```

   The VersionFormat value now has `XN.DD` instead of `XN.NN`.
   This will ignore the fact that 1.25 -> 1.15 is a downgrade.
8. Prepare for a reboot. I.e. close unnecessary applications and plug in power adapter. Because it'll happen automatically after running the installer.
9. Run `H2OFFT-W.exe`. 
   Upon reboot, you'll see a bios installing progress bar.
10. After that is done, press <kbd>F2</kbd> during startup to get to bios. 
    The version should now be 1.15.
11. At this point I set a password, turned off UEFI, and swapped my hard drive out for a fresh SSD. Ubuntu finally installed.

Comment: Holy ...! Thanks A lot man. I spent so long on this I downgraded my driver and boom it works. Really its unprofessional what acer did.

Comment: great ! I'm glad you 've solved