# I cant boot any linux distro install in my acer laptop

Tags: laptop, bios, acer

After a long time using Windows (and getting tired of it) I was trying to install EndeavourOS in my Acer E5 575 laptop.

I had no problems with the installation, and everything was smooth as butter. When the installation was completed, I rebooted my device to start using EndevourOS, but when the laptop starts booting, I got a message saying that there is no bootable device.

This happened with a lot of distros (I tried multiple times with each):

- EndeavourOS
- ArcoLinux
- Linux Mint
- Ubuntu
- Manjaro

Not even one of them booted once after installation.

I discovered [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309238/installing-linux-on-acer-laptop/309240?newreg=47a3c7addaa64018ad17833d9076628c) that I think it may be the solution for my problems, but in the Acer website I can no longer select the version of the BIOS drivers I want to download.

Acer is just making me do whatever they want to do with my laptop, and I just want to run some Linux and have a nice developer experience compared to Windblows.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

How can I downgrade the Acer E5 575 BIOS drivers to properly boot a fresh install of Linux?

Comment: Acer's website still has bios available for your particular device on there website[0]. Are you sure downgrading bios will solve your problem though? https://www.acer.com/us-en/support/product-support/E5-575/downloads?suggest=e5%20575;4

Comment: Welcome, before jumping to BIOS firmware modification (which could potentially be disastrous), try with different BIOS configuration options. For example, you could try disabling secure boot. [Check this case](https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/) with similar situation.

Comment: Yes, please don't follow that thread, it is *seven years old*! It is extremely unlikely that it is still relevant today.

Comment: And please [edit] your question and clarify when you get the error. Is it directly after [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test)? Or do you see a boot menu (a list of available operating systems) which includes Windows and a Linux, and then you select Linux and that is when you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the problem!

What I did was just follow the instructions of [this post](https://itsfoss.com/no-bootable-device-found-ubuntu/).
Thank you all for the responses, and specially to [schrodingerscatcuriosity](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/338177/schrodingerscatcuriosity) for providing the post in the comments! I looked for answers to this problem for literally ***hours*** and never found that post.